# Using GDB to look at stack

Tags: exploit, assembly

I'm not experienced with GDB, and trying to examine an executable. I want to find the value of `%eax` at certain times, and whether it's ever `called` or `jumped`.

I was only given the executable, and it doesn't have any breakpoints.

If I enter `run`, the program runs and then finishes, and no commands work—I get "No symbol table is loaded" and "No registers."

Dissembling the executable (`objdump -d`) doesn't help, the result is 130,000 lines long.

How can I do this analysis?

Update: I used PEDA successfully; I set breakpoints at the functions and stepped through the program using `next`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you really need to set a breakpoint somewhere if you want `gdb` to stop before the program end.

Then, you should really try to use `peda`, a set of configuration and Python scripts for `gdb` designed for reverse-engineering software.

Take a look at:

- [The official page](http://ropshell.com/peda/)
- [The Github page](https://github.com/longld/peda)
- [Slides from BlackHat'12](http://ropshell.com/peda/Linux_Interactive_Exploit_Development_with_GDB_and_PEDA_Slides.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But does it help with my problem?

Comment: In fact, yes. Because the stack of the current process is displayed by `peda` (look at the `stack` section of the display). And, in fact, each time you hit the `nexti` or `stepi` function, the new stack is displayed. So, I guess this is exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I re-read your question, and it seems that you did not set a breakpoint at all. You have to understand that setting a first breakpoint should be prior to the `run` command. Because, if you don't, you will never be given the opportunity to interact with `gdb` and your program.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add any break points. Do you think it's feasible to dissemble the program and then execute the assembly line by line? Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't add any breakpoint?"... If you can start a PTRACE, you should be able to do so... Try to get the entrypoint through `info files`, then set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Ah, I thought you needed to add breakpoints in the source, and then recompile. If what you say is possible, then I'll simply do that. Thanks.